# is guice-struts2-plugin-2.0 support the Struts 2.x?

Tags: java, struts, guice

I am using Guice 2.0 and its struts plugin 'guice-struts2-plugin-2.0' in my application. The struts version is 'Struts2-core-2.1.8.1 and application server is Jboss 4.2.2. 
when deploying application getting problem

```
java.lang.NullPointerException :  at com.google.inject.struts2.GuiceObjectFactory
$ProvidedInterceptor.destroy(GuiceObjectFactory.java:216)
here is my stack trace 

23:06:11,390 INFO  [TomcatDeployer] deploy, ctxPath=/
HelloGuiceServlet, warUrl=.../tmp/deploy/tmp2295HelloGuiceServlet-
exp.war/
23:06:11,390 INFO  [ContainerBase] Container
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/
HelloGuiceServlet].[jsp] has not been started
23:06:11,390 INFO  [ContainerBase] Container
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/
HelloGuiceServlet].[default] has not been started
23:06:11,390 ERROR [BaseModelMBean] Exception invoking method destroy
java.lang.NullPointerException
       at com.google.inject.struts2.GuiceObjectFactory
$ProvidedInterceptor.destroy(GuiceObjectFactory.java:216)
       at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.cleanup(Dispatcher.java:
298)
       at
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.PrepareOperations.cleanupDispatcher(PrepareOperations.java:
179)
       at
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.destroy(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:
100)
       at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.release(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:
332)
       at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStop(StandardContext.java:
3757)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:
4517)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.destroy(ContainerBase.java:
1163)
       at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.destroy(StandardContext.java:
4617)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at
org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:
296)
       at
org.jboss.mx.server.RawDynamicInvoker.invoke(RawDynamicInvoker.java:
164)
       at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:
659)
       at
org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployer.java:
175)
       at
org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer.performDeploy(TomcatDeployer.java:
104)
       at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebDeployer.start(AbstractWebDeployer.java:
375)
       at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:83)
       at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startService(WebModule.java:61)
       at
org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:
289)
       at
org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:
245)
       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor94.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at
org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:
155)
       at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
       at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
       at
org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:
264)
       at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:
659)
       at org.jboss.system.ServiceController
$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
       at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
       at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:
417)
       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at
org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:
155)
       at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
       at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
       at
org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:
264)
       at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:
659)
       at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
       at $Proxy44.start(Unknown Source)
       at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebContainer.start(AbstractWebContainer.java:
466)
       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor93.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at
org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:
155)
       at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
       at
org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:
133)
       at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
       at
org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:
142)
       at
org.jboss.mx.interceptor.DynamicInterceptor.invoke(DynamicInterceptor.java:
97)
       at
org.jboss.system.InterceptorServiceMBeanSupport.invokeNext(InterceptorServiceMBeanSupport.java:
238)
       at
org.jboss.wsf.container.jboss42.DeployerInterceptor.start(DeployerInterceptor.java:
87)
       at org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptorSupport
$XMBeanInterceptor.start(SubDeployerInterceptorSupport.java:188)
       at
org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptor.invoke(SubDeployerInterceptor.java:
95)
       at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
       at
org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:
264)
       at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:
659)
       at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
       at $Proxy45.start(Unknown Source)
       at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
       at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
       at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor21.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at
org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:
155)
       at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
       at
org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:
133)
       at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
       at
org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:
142)
       at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
       at
org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:
264)
       at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:
659)
       at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
       at $Proxy9.deploy(Unknown Source)
       at
org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.deploy(URLDeploymentScanner.java:
421)
       at
org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.scan(URLDeploymentScanner.java:
610)
       at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner
$ScannerThread.doScan(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:263)
       at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner
$ScannerThread.loop(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:274)
       at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner
$ScannerThread.run(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:225)
23:06:11,406 WARN  [ServiceController] Problem starting service
jboss.web.deployment:war=HelloGuiceServlet.war,id=-343052674
org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: Error during deploy; -
nested throwable: (javax.management.RuntimeOperationsException:
Exception invoking method destroy)
       at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebDeployer.start(AbstractWebDeployer.java:
384)
       at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:83)
       at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startService(WebModule.java:61)
       at
org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:
289)
       at
org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:
245)
       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor94.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at
org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:
155)
       at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
       at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
       at
org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:
264)
       at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:
659)
       at org.jboss.system.ServiceController
$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
       at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
       at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:
417)
       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at
org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:
155)
       at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
       at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
       at
org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:
264)
       at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:
659)
       at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
       at $Proxy44.start(Unknown Source)
       at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebContainer.start(AbstractWebContainer.java:
466)
       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor93.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at
org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:
155)
       at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
       at
org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:
133)
       at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
       at
org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:
142)
       at
org.jboss.mx.interceptor.DynamicInterceptor.invoke(DynamicInterceptor.java:
97)
       at
org.jboss.system.InterceptorServiceMBeanSupport.invokeNext(InterceptorServiceMBeanSupport.java:
238)
       at
org.jboss.wsf.container.jboss42.DeployerInterceptor.start(DeployerInterceptor.java:
87)
       at org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptorSupport
$XMBeanInterceptor.start(SubDeployerInterceptorSupport.java:188)
       at
org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptor.invoke(SubDeployerInterceptor.java:
95)
       at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
       at
org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:
264)
       at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:
659)
       at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
       at $Proxy45.start(Unknown Source)
       at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
       at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
       at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor21.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at
org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:
155)
       at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
       at
org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:
133)
       at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
       at
org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:
142)
       at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
       at
org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:
264)
       at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:
659)
       at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
       at $Proxy9.deploy(Unknown Source)
       at
org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.deploy(URLDeploymentScanner.java:
421)
       at
org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.scan(URLDeploymentScanner.java:
610)
       at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner
$ScannerThread.doScan(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:263)
       at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner
$ScannerThread.loop(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:274)
       at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner
$ScannerThread.run(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:225)
Caused by: javax.management.RuntimeOperationsException: Exception
invoking method destroy
       at
org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:
304)
       at
org.jboss.mx.server.RawDynamicInvoker.invoke(RawDynamicInvoker.java:
164)
       at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:
659)
       at
org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployer.java:
175)
       at
org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer.performDeploy(TomcatDeployer.java:
104)
       at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebDeployer.start(AbstractWebDeployer.java:
375)
       ... 65 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
       at com.google.inject.struts2.GuiceObjectFactory
$ProvidedInterceptor.destroy(GuiceObjectFactory.java:216)
       at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.cleanup(Dispatcher.java:
298)
       at
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.PrepareOperations.cleanupDispatcher(PrepareOperations.java:
179)
       at
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.destroy(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:
100)
       at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.release(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:
332)
       at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStop(StandardContext.java:
3757)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:
4517)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.destroy(ContainerBase.java:
1163)
       at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.destroy(StandardContext.java:
4617)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at
org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:
296)
       ... 70 more
```

Is really google guice supports the Struts2Integration ??? is guice-struts2-plugin-2.0 is mature plugin for struts ???

Any Help Please.

Answer (score 0):

The [guice wiki](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Struts2Integration) page is an example of using guice with struts 2.2 and up. It looks like you are using struts 2.1.8.1 so that example won't work for you. I had the same problem but was able to use guice with struts < 2.2 by using the example on the [source code](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/source/browse/#svn/tags/2.0/struts2). Its a little more work but it does work.

Comment: Thanks kodova for replying . I resolved that issue long time ago. its working fine with struts 2.1.8.1,I forgot to add the guice-servlet-2.0.jar.guice-struts2-plugin-2.0.jar working with guice2.0.